# Python Selenium Recaphta I am not a robot - how to bypass

Tags: python, selenium

First of all, I am not by any means an expert scraping the web, selenium, or have a good understanding of html...

I am trying to download a CSV file that is hidden behind a 'recaptcha - i am not a robot'.  I first must login to the website and then there is link that generates the I am not a robot captcha.  It is the kind that you just click a box and must hit 'yes, i am not a robot' button.

I can't figure out how to get this to work.  I've seen things about finding the x/y coordinates of where the box pops up and clicking, but I can't seem to figure that out.   There seems potentially other methods, but I'm just having a hard time deciphering   what to do and then how to do.  My code thus far...

```
import selenium
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("mywebsite")

username = browser.find_element_by_id("Email")
password = browser.find_element_by_id("Password")

username.send_keys('<<MY_EMAIL_FOR_LOGIN>>')
password.send_keys('<<MY_PASSWORD_FOR_LOGIN>>')

browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="container"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/form/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/input[6]').click()  #button to 'login' 

# so far so good - I am logged in!


elements = browser.find_element_by_id("patient-export-button")
elements

browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elements)

# the lines above will cause the recaptcha popup to appear.  
# now I am STUCK!
```

I have to now click the checkbox & hit 'yes' in order for my file to download.  Sometimes when I hit the checkbox I get all these stupid 'find the car' images which are a pain in the ass for me to solve even as a human...

Any help on solving this recaptcha thing would be appreciated.

Comment: most sites offer some sort of api ... you should try the "contact us" button on the site and ask them about some supported way of doing it ... recaptcha is really going to be hard to beat with selenium ... after all its entire purpose of being is to prevent things like selenium

Comment: If there is a recaptcha, then they want to stop scripts like what you are writing, So You should not do this on that particular site